# Zend 1.12 login not working

Tags: zend-framework

i'm creating a login system using salt and password two columns but it's not working my code of action

```
public function indexAction() {
    $form = new Admin_Form_Login();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            if ($this->_process($form->getValues())) {
                // We're authenticated! Redirect to the home page
                $this->_helper->redirector('', 'dashboard');
            }  else {
                echo 'Password is wrong';
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}

protected function _process($values) {
    // Get our authentication adapter and check credentials
    $adapter = $this->_getAuthAdapter();
    $adapter->setIdentity($values['email']);
    $adapter->setCredential($values['password']);

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();
        $auth->getStorage()->write($user);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

protected function _getAuthAdapter() {
    $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);

    $authAdapter->setTableName('eg_user_login')
            ->setIdentityColumn('email')
            ->setCredentialColumn('password')
            ->setCredentialTreatment("MD5(CONCAT(? , salt))");

    return $authAdapter;
}
```

and code of registration action is

```
 $regForm = new Admin_Form_Register();
    $this->view->form = $regForm;
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($regForm->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) {
            $values = $regForm->getValues($this->_request->getPost());
            $pass = $values['pass1'];
            $salt = sha1($pass);
            $password = MD5($salt . $pass);
            $data = array(
                'f_name' => $values['fname'],
                'l_name' => $values['lname'],
                'gender' => $values['gender'],
                'email' => $values['email'],
                'contact' => $values['contact'],
                'password' => $password,
                'salt' => $salt,
                'created_on' => date("d-m-y"),
                'user_role' => $values['userrole'],
                'status' => 0
            );
            $db = new Admin_Model_Userreg();
            $db->insert($data);
        }
    }
```

it is displaying any error,i think problem in encryption and decryption in password.
login page is not redirecting to dashboard and not storing the user instance .... please help me. thank you.

Comment: it is not displaying any error,i think problem in encryption and decryption in password. login page is not redirecting to dashboard and not storing the user instance .... please help me. thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the form's action is post ad that the is a url handled by `indexAction()`? Are you sure that the execution flow is getting past `$form->isValid()`? What value is the `_process()` method returning? Are you sure that execution flow is getting to the redirector line? Bottom line: the first step is to know the execution flow for your given set of input values.

Comment: thanks i have solve .error was at the  MD5($salt . $pass) .ihave used  MD5( $pass.$salt) than it is works fine. Thanks  [David Weinraub](http://stackoverflow.com/users/131824/david-weinraub)